# How to populate https GET responese in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to JAVA/JSP world, trying to populate https GET response in jsp page, bet getting 500 error. please help out tho solve this. HTTPS Get call works fine in Rest client.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><%@

    page import="java.util.Date"                                       %><%@ 
    page import="java.net.*"                                           %><%@ 
    page import="java.io.*"                                            %><%@ 
    page import="java.util.HashMap"                                    %><%@ 
    page import="javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection"                     %><%@ 
    page import="org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils"                        %><%@ 
    page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"         %><% 

    String httpsURL = "https://localhost:8002/";
    URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    String json        = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");

    %>

    <%=json%>
```

Comment: Why don't you let the browser do it?

Comment: API is not exposed out side world & accessible only inside office network